# How can I store data against specific contact ID?

Tags: xml, android, database, contacts

I want to store some additional data for each contact on Android.
I would have in mind creating my own database table for it, and then bind them to the real contact via a unique id.

I am wondering if Android has built in functionality to store additional data against contacts?

**EDIT 2**
Is there a defined field for birthday of the contact?
How do I store a date field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is `ContactsContract.Data` class declares Content URI to store additional contact information ( phones, emails and IM statuses for example are all implemented in similar ways)
Take a look at `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds` for an example of implementation.
Basically  you've got `CONTACT_ID`,`MIME_TYPE` and data columns to store data you want